# React native camera recordasync start failed error

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

When I click on the record button on android device react-native-camera throw an error "Start failed".

```
Error: start failed.
    at createErrorFromErrorData (NativeModules.js:155)
    at NativeModules.js:104
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (MessageQueue.js:414)
    at MessageQueue.js:127
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:314)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:126)
    at debuggerWorker.js:80
```

1. Permission code has been added to AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2. All permission is granted checked using PermissionsAndroid.
3. Tried passing quality options as mentioned in [Link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1954)

```
setCameraReady = () => {
    this.setState({
      cameraReady: true
    });
};
```

```
startRecording = async () => {
    const { cameraReady } = this.state;
    if (cameraReady) {
      try {
        // default to mp4 for android as codec is not set
        const { uri, codec = 'mp4' } = await this.camera.recordAsync({
          maxDuration: 30
        });
        console.log(uri)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };
```

```
 stopRecording = () => {
    this.camera.stopRecording();
  };
```

```
<RNCamera
    style={cameraStyle}
    ref={(ref) => {
      this.camera = ref;
    }}
    type={cameraType}
    mirrorImage={cameraType !== 'back'}
    androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
      title: 'Permission to use camera',
      message: 'We need your permission to use your camera phone',
      buttonPositive: 'Ok',
      buttonNegative: 'Cancel'
    }}
    androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
      title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
      message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
      buttonPositive: 'Ok',
      buttonNegative: 'Cancel'
    }}
    onCameraReady={this.setCameraReady}
   />
```

Should get URI when recordAsync promise gets resolved.

Comment: I have narrow it down to issue related to the onePlus android camera. I have tested the same app on multiple devices like Samsung, Vivo, Oppo, and Redmi all works fine. But same app crash after start failed error in onePlus.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the react-native-camera team.

Updating react-native-camera to latest version i.e 1.10.0 fixed the issue.